# Get dependent drop-down result to label

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to adapt dependent drop-down script for my need.(Google scrips)
So, far everything works fine.
This is what I am trying to achieve: https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiYmM4Y2QzYzktMzViYy00NWE5LTlkNDEtODQ3OTA5ZWY1MGRkIiwidCI6IjY0MDQ3OTA4LTg1NmUtNDdkNi05OGEwLTc4ZjAwNGViMTU2MyIsImMiOjl9

This is what I achieved so far:
https://alqoritm.com/embed.html

Instead of having Median Salary result in drop-down, I want it to be shown as label. (as on above power bi tool)

Probably I have to get value from unique array. But I am not familiar with java script /google scripts.

```
function doGet(e) {
  
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
  var colors = getColors();
  var fruits = getFruits();
  var classParams = getClasses();
  var brands = getBrands();
  htmlOutput.message = '';
  htmlOutput.colors = colors;
  htmlOutput.fruits = fruits;
  htmlOutput.classParams = classParams;
  htmlOutput.brands = brands;
  return htmlOutput.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function doPost(e) {
  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  
  var name = e.parameters.name.toString();
  var color = e.parameters.color.toString();
  var fruit = e.parameters.fruit.toString();
  var classParam = e.parameters.classParam.toString();
  var brand = e.parameters.brand.toString();
  
  AddRecord(name, color, fruit, classParam, brand);
  
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
  var colors = getColors();
  var fruits = getFruits();
  var classParams = getClasses();
  var brands = getBrands();
  htmlOutput.message = 'Record Added';
  htmlOutput.colors = colors;
  htmlOutput.fruits = fruits;
  htmlOutput.classParams = classParams;
  htmlOutput.brands = brands;

  return htmlOutput.evaluate(); 
  
}

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

function getColors() { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LOV"); 
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if(return_array.indexOf(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue()) === -1) {
        return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue());
      }
  }


  return return_array.filter(onlyUnique);  
}

function getFruits(color) { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LOV"); 
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() === color) {
        return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue());
      }
  }


  return return_array.filter(onlyUnique);  
}

function getClasses(color, fruit) { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LOV"); 
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if((lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() === color) && (lovSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() === fruit)) {
        return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue());
      }
  }

  return return_array.filter(onlyUnique);  
}

function getBrands(color, fruit, classParam) { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LOV"); 
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if((lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() === color) && (lovSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() === fruit) && (lovSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue() === classParam)) {
        return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue());
      }
  }
  return return_array.filter(onlyUnique);  
}


function getUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
}
```

here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function GetFruit(color) 
    {
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {

    console.log(ar);
    
    fruit.length = 0;
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    fruit.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      fruit.appendChild(option);    
    });
    
    }).getFruits(color);
    
    };

    function GetClass(color, fruit) 
    {
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {

    console.log(ar);
    
    classParam.length = 0;
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    classParam.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      classParam.appendChild(option);    
    });
    
    }).getClasses(color, fruit);
    
    };

    function GetBrand(color, fruit, classParam) 
    {
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {

    console.log(ar);
    
    brand.length = 0;
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    brand.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      brand.appendChild(option);    
    });
    
    }).getBrands(color, fruit, classParam);
    
    };

  function onSelect() 
  {
    var carID = document.getElementById("brand").value;
    document.getElementById("BrandValue").innerHTML = carID;
  };
  </script>  

   <style>
  .dropdown {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content p {
  text-align: center;
}

    body{
      background-color: white; 
      color: black; 
    }
    .align{
      text-align: center; 
    }
    .margin{
      margin-bottom: 10px; 
    }
    h1{
      font-size: 20pt; 
    }

    h2{
      font-size: 16pt; 
    }

label {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", Myriad, "Liberation Sans", "Nimbus Sans L", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:rgb(23, 61, 110)
}
.myDiv {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;    
  text-align: center;
  height: 600px;
  width: 50%;
}
.center-screen {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

select{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

</style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <?var url = getUrl();?>
<div class="center-screen">
    <form method="post" action="<?= url ?>" >

      <!-- color -->
      <label style="font-size: 40px" >Specialism</label><br>
      <select name="color" id="color" style="font-size: 20px" onchange="GetFruit(this.value)" >
      <option value="" ></option>
      <? for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) { ?>      
      <option value="<?= colors[i] ?>" ><?= colors[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
      </select><br><br>

      <!-- fruit -->
      <label style="font-size: 40px" >Employment Type</label><br>
      <select name="fruit" id="fruit" style="font-size: 20px" onchange="GetClass(color.value, this.value)" >
      <option value="" ></option>
      <? for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) { ?>      
      <option value="<?= fruits[i] ?>" ><?= fruits[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
      </select><br><br>

      <!-- class -->
      <label style="font-size: 40px" >Job Title</label><br>
      <select name="classParam" id="classParam" style="font-size: 20px" onchange="GetBrand(color.value, fruit.value, this.value)" >
      <option value="" ></option>
      <? for(var i = 0; i < classParams.length; i++) { ?>      
      <option value="<?= classParams[i] ?>" ><?= classParams[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
      </select><br><br>

      <!-- brand -->
      <label style="font-size: 40px" >Median Salary</label><br>
      <select name="brand" id="brand" style="font-size: 60px" onchange="onSelect()">
      </select><br><br>

<span id="BrandValue" ></span>

<!--
  <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" style="font-size: 20px" /> 
<span style="font-size: 20px" ><?= message ?></span>
-->
    </form>
</div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to use:

```
  function onSelect() 
  {
  var carID = document.getElementById("brand").value;
  document.getElementById("BrandValue").innerHTML = carID;
  };
```

But it only shows result after drop-down in Median Salary selected. But I want to remove Median Salary drop-down so I am hoping to get result when Job Title drop-down selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the last dropdown and change your function:

```
function getBrands(color, fruit, classParam) { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LOV"); 
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if((lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() === color) && (lovSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() === fruit) && (lovSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue() === classParam)) {
        return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue());
      }
  }
     return return_array[0] //maybe [1], it seems to have an empty first value
    }
```

put a script at the end of the body:

```
<script>
function tryThis(color, fruit, classParam){
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
     document.getElementById("BrandValue").innerHTML = result;
   }).getBrands(color, fruit, classParam);
}
</script>
```

change in `onchange="tryThis(color.value, fruit.value, this.value)"`

I never used gs before, if this doesn't work try to find a solution here (those methods are used to call gs functions in js):
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#index.html_2

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, but I get error: ReferenceError: document is not defined (line 106, file "Code") I tied <script src="Code.gs"></script>
  </body>

Comment: no worry bro, i changed the answer just let me know if this time is correct